# whether to use refinerycms or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

Me and a bunch of our friends decided to make a website with ruby on rails.  Our question is whether refinerycms is fit with out website.  What we are building is a place where our community would sign in and post up a bunch of pictures, videos, live streams, or articles/blogs.  The front page would be have top feeds and featured articles.  That is the idea for the most part.  We thought about refinerycms but after looking into refinery it doesn't seem so fit and was wondering if its better if we just start it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know rails and don't want to spend many hours learning.(I love it. It's fun, but not for everyone), go for wordpress.

Wordpress is easier to set up and deploy to a server.

All web hotels usually works with PHP and Mysql out of the box, witch wordpress depends on

Rails depends on ruby and that makes the server configuration more complex.

For a developer Ruby on rails is gold. But, if your main focus is to get a blog up, its to much to learn.

If you want to learn ROR go to [railscast](http://railscast.com) and get a pro subscription. It's the best way to pick up rails tricks

Comment: i definitely want to learn more about rails, its a great web app that i enjoy learning.  thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

If your website mostly functions as a blog, the Refinery would be a great choice, IMHO. On the other hand, expect to do some programming on your own part if you need features such as the ones you mentioned (i.e. Live streams). On the other hand, if you're completely new to Rails, the it might be slightly more challenging, but don't let that stop you. :)

Comment: thank you for the advice, i love learning rails so i will go the hard way!